# How to supress a notification pop-up?

Tags: android, push-notification

There are some notifications on Android, like the Spotify playback notification or charging notifications from the Android-System that don't visually pop up. I'm looking for the parameter inside those notifications which determines this behaviour. Anyone knows how this is done?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you want a non-dismissable notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set the Notification flags to 
    Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR or Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT